# Creating automatic backups with rsync from ext4 file system to afps file system on another device (local network)

Tags: macos, ubuntu, backup, rsync, ext4

I shared an external hard drive (AFPS file format) on my macosx via local file sharing to my ubuntu server (ext4 file format). I would like to use rsync to automatically sync folders from the ext4 file system to the afps file format on the macosx external hard drive. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: What have you tried, where did you get stuck?

Comment: Local file systems are irrelevant for network shares.

Comment: I wanted to make sure that data could be transferred between these two file systems. I should not have a problem implementing the commands for this feature.

Comment: Again, the file systems are irrelevant for network shares. As long as said shares are set up with the correct read/write permissions (for the share, this is *independent* of local file/folders permissions). So, what have you tried already?